# Is it possible to By Pass the UAC dialog while launching a process (.exe file) from c#?

Tags: c#, windows, uac

Is it possible to By Pass the UAC dialog while launching a process (.exe file) from c#  code without changing any system registry configurations?

Comment: Assuming you mean to run a process as elevated: nope. Otherwise everyone would implement that and UAC would be pointless.

Comment: Sure, if so, everyone could just do it on your computer as well. Do you want this? I doubt so. Would be highly critical, wouldn´t it?

Comment: No. It would be stupid if you could. *I'm malware, and I want to infect this machine. I know! I'll just run myself and bypass the UAC dialog!* Common sense tells you this would not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer your question: no this is not possible. If it were possible, most (all?) software would opt in to this behavior, and render the UAC dialog pointless.